# Operation on column 3 based on column 2 value

Tags: awk

I have this file

```
$ cat test.txt
49808830/ccs 9492 TACA 3
175833950/ccs 971 ACCC 1
180422692/ccs 971 ACCC 10
110952448/ccs 9714 TAGAG 2
117309969/ccs 9714 TAGAG 4
119998610/ccs 9714 TAGAG 5
171509463/ccs 9714 TAGAT 4
```

For each unique $2 value, I need to put "same" at the end of all lines with that $2 value if there is just 1 common $3 value for all occurrences of that $2 value, otherwise I need to write "diff".

I should get :

```
49808830/ccs 9492 TACA 3 same #print "same" for line when only one occurence of column 2
175833950/ccs 971 ACCC 1 same 
180422692/ccs 971 ACCC 10 same 
110952448/ccs 9714 TAGAG 2 diff
117309969/ccs 9714 TAGAG 4 diff
119998610/ccs 9714 TAGAG 5 diff 
171509463/ccs 9714 TAGAT 4 diff #because "TAGAT" is different of "TAGAG"
```

Comment: Printing with `$1` and `$3` in the `END` block will just print the values from the last record. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: Not really. I was expecting to separate both parts in two different outputs. But if I can do both in the same output, it should be fine too

Comment: is the data guaranteed to already be sorted by the 2nd column?

Comment: this appears to be two separate problems ... sum up column 4 ***OR*** generate `same/diff` strings .... with both problems based on the grouping of data by the 2nd column; since you already have an answer for the 1st problem I'd suggest editing the question to remove all references to the 1st problem and just focus on the 2nd problem; this should eliminate any confusion as to what you're looking for

Comment: @anubhava Printing with `$1` and `$3` in the `END` block is undefined behavior so it'll do different things in different awk versions. In some it'll print the values from the last record read, in others it'll print null strings, and in yet others it could do anything else (though I haven't personally seen any other actions).

Comment: @pedro Regarding "...if the column 3 value is the same or not" - the same as what?

Comment: I read this question multiple times over 2 days and couldn't figure out the "same" vs "diff" requirements but after reading the first script in [@markp-fuso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77808167/1745001) I think I finally get it - for each unique $2 value, you want to put "same" at the end of all lines with that $2 value if there is just 1 common $3 value for all occurrences of that $2 value, otherwise you want "diff", right? And all the other information about summing $4 values has nothing to do with "same" vs "diff", is that also right?

Comment: When someone (Ed, in this case) needs 2 days, and an answer from someone else to figure out what you _probably_ want to achieve, then you should put more effort in asking the correct question.

Comment: Sorry, I was away and no possibility to answer you back. Both @markp-fuso and Ed solutions work well in my case. I also edited my post to make it clear, as Ed suggested in his previous comment. Sorry again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2-pass solution using `GNU awk` (for multidimensional arrays):

```
awk '
FNR==NR { a[$2][$3]
          next
        }
        { print $0, (length(a[$2]) == 1 ? "same" : "diff") }
' test.txt test.txt
```

A 1-pass solution using `GNU awk` (for multidimensional arrays):

```
awk '
    { lines[NR] = $0
      col2[NR]  = $2
      a[$2][$3]
    }
END { for (i=1;i<=NR;i++)
          print lines[i], (length(a[col2[i]]) == 1 ? "same" : "diff")
    }
' test.txt
```

A 2-pass solution that should work with all `awk` versions:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { key = $2 SUBSEP $3
          if (! seen[key]++) 
             count[$2]++
          next
        }
        { print $0, (count[$2] == 1 ? "same" : "diff") }
' test.txt test.txt
```

A 1-pass solution that should work with all `awk` versions:

```
awk '
    { lines[NR] = $0
      col2[NR]  = $2
      key       = $2 SUBSEP $3
      if (! seen[key]++)
         count[$2]++
    }
END { for (i=1;i<=NR;i++)
          print lines[i], (count[col2[i]] == 1 ? "same" : "diff")
      }
' test.txt
```

These all generate:

```
49808830/ccs 9492 TACA 3 same
175833950/ccs 971 ACCC 1 same
180422692/ccs 971 ACCC 10 same
110952448/ccs 9714 TAGAG 2 diff
117309969/ccs 9714 TAGAG 4 diff
119998610/ccs 9714 TAGAG 5 diff
171509463/ccs 9714 TAGAT 4 diff
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk and 1 pass just storing the values for one $2 at a time in memory:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    if ( $2 == prev[2] ) {
        if ( $3 != prev[3] ) {
            type = "diff"
        }
    }
    else {
        prt()
        type = "same"
        numVals = 0
    }
    vals[++numVals] = $0
    split($0,prev)
}
END { prt() }

function prt(    i) {
    for ( i=1; i<=numVals; i++ ) {
        print vals[i], type
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk test.txt
49808830/ccs 9492 TACA 3 same
175833950/ccs 971 ACCC 1 same
180422692/ccs 971 ACCC 10 same
110952448/ccs 9714 TAGAG 2 diff
117309969/ccs 9714 TAGAG 4 diff
119998610/ccs 9714 TAGAG 5 diff
171509463/ccs 9714 TAGAT 4 diff
```